# QTableView обновление, QtConcurrent

Tags: qt, viewmodel

Модель сохраняет числа в переменной, числа читаются из файла отдельным потоком. Если не производить никаких действий над gui (кликать по ячейкам, сворачивать разварачивать, и т.д.), то отображение обновляться не будет. (Если кликать по ячейке, то обновит данные именно в этой ячейке, если сворачивать/разворачивать то обновляет всю таблицу) Пытался эмитить dataChanged() в моделе при очередном сложении, все равно безрезультатно..  :( В какую сторону хоть смотреть подскажите!?

Comment: Покажите, как вы работаете с сигналом `dataChanged`. Если с ним всё правильно, то должно обновляться. Сигнал должен отправляться после изменения данных.

Comment: emit dataChanged(this->index(3, 3), this->index(3, 3)); Тобишь посылаю индекс ячейки где содержится значение, метод data() у модели переопределен.

Comment: уверены в правильности индексов? Попробуйте для эксперимента обновить всю таблицу: `emit dataChanged(this->index(0, 0), this->index(rowCount(), columnCount()));`

Comment: не помогло, но спасибо за попытку, благодаря Вам мне остается грешить на второй поток. Скорее всего криво его использую.

Comment: Если сигнал действительно посылается, и при этом данные в модели обновлены ДО отсылки сигнала, то всё должно работать. Посмотрите отладчиком, отсылается ли сигнал. Второй поток, скорее всего, не при чем.

Comment: Через отладчик пошагово данные обновляются нормально :) Почему я грешу на второй поток: после того как данные из файла считаны, они передаются в метод промежуточного класса (через указатель) этот метод эмитит что данные пришли. Так вот, я плохо знаком с потоками поэтому выбрал qtconcurrent из за кажущейся простоты. Загвоздка была в том что модель не видела эмит этого сигнала. Поэтому тип коннекта пришлось поменять на DirectConnection.

Comment: Через вывод qDebug() я отследил что цепочка работает. Но вот застопорился на этом моменте.

Comment: DirectConnection не может отправить сигнал в другой поток.

Comment: Что вы выводили через qDebug? И где этот qDebug у вас находится?  Попробуйте между обновлением данных и эмитом сигнала вставить qDebug и проверить, действительно ли данные обновились. И вообще, без кода у нас с вами беспредметный разговор.

Comment: через qDebug() выводил текст-метки, что данные были отправлены в метод класса, что метод класса отправил сигнал, что модель приняла этот сигнал. Да, извиняюсь что без кода, просто я сильно абстрагировался. но цепочка получается такая [QtConcurrent::run(Foo)]  ->[Class A] -> Signal(DirectConnection) ->model ->signal ->[TableView]. Если убрать direct connection то цепочка рушится (согласно меткам qDebug() ). Как я понимаю мне из функции в QConcurrent надо обратно в мейн стрим эмитить и оттуда уже цепочку запускать.